# Javascript call other function

Tags: javascript

I have some problems with Javascript and calling 'function in function'.
I have this code:

Sorry about pastebin.com/tKVNmGLJ , again problems with pasting a code.

And i need to call first function in second one, but only cut of that code:

```
$('#delete-confirmation-modal-document').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

    var invoker = $(e.relatedTarget);

    $('button.confirm', this).off('click').on('click', function(){
        $.get(invoker.data('href'), function(resp){
            invoker.parents('.thumbnail').parent('div').remove();
            $('#delete-confirmation-modal-document').modal('hide');
        });
    });
});
```

cause there is no button to confirm.

Edit:
Sorry for less information!
I have drop box, for uploading a file. When you upload file you see the file in that drop box and down bellow drop box, but when you refresh page you don't have this file in that drop box (what is correct). But problem is, if you upload file and you have uploaded mistaken file you have button 'Remove' (talking about drop box), so you remove the file and it's gone from box, but it's not removed down bellow drop box (it is removed but I have to refresh page to see that changes).
So the first function is removing that file from down bellow drop box, let's call it 'other box' for example, if it's already uploaded and when you click 'Remove' from that other box, you have modal to confirm that changes to remove file, and it's removed correctly. Second remove function is removing file only from drop box, but I need to remove it from other box too. So i need somehow to call that function and to remove that added file. I tried to paste that cut of code in second code but it's not working, I know why but not sure how to write  that.

Comment: If you want any kind of help you have at least provide some code sample, in any case I suggest reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the first function, what is the second? Please provide an example limited to only relevant code.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: @user10099265 see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

`$('button.confirm')` probably should be `$('button#confirm')`

... with the HTML, this is just a guess - because it's not reproducible.